# POST request returning index.html body instead of appropriate response

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I've been working on a web app where all the post requests work fine when the frontend is hosted locally through a proxy to the backend, which is hosted on heroku. However when deploying the frontend (on firebase) the requests still return successfully, but instead of {success: true} it returns the index.html file from the build directory, and does perform any actions on the database.

Relevant code on heroku:

```
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 'Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,content-type,application/json');
  next();
});

app.post('/updateBoard', async (req, res) => {
  const { board_id, itemName, color, index, gameInfo } = req.body;
  await functions.updateBoard(board_id, itemName, color, index, gameInfo)
  res.send({ success: true })
})

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App listening on port ${port}!`));
```

Respective frontend function:

```
const updateBoardData = async (
    board_id,
    itemName,
    color,
    index,
    gameInfo
  ) => {
    var res = await fetch("/updateBoard", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        board_id: board_id,
        itemName: itemName,
        color: color,
        index: index,
        gameInfo: gameInfo,
      }),
    });
    console.log(res);
  };
```

Output from deployed: 
`<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head> ... </html>`

Output from localhost:
{"success":true}

Comment: Hi, can you add what kind of output you're getting? It would be great to understand it more clearly.

Comment: Hi, both requests succeed with status 200, but it outputs the whole index.html from the build file. I've updated the post to show more info, let me know if I should add anything more specific!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to solve this issue by making the route in the fetch to be nameofproject.herokuapp.com/updateBoard since apparently the proxy did not work once the app was deployed.